# Procurar valores duplicados - Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, procv

Como retornar uma empresa com base em um valor, mesmo que a Matriz tenha varios duplicados. Pode retornar o primeiro encontrado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: `=PROCV` procura somente na primeira coluna, então não é recomendada para procurar numa matriz 2D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi utilizando a função matricial:

`{=SEERRO(ÍNDICE($A$1:$C$1;;MENOR(SE((COL($A$2:$C$5)-COL($A$2)+1)*($A$2:$C$5=$F$2)=0;99;(COL($A$2:$C$5)-COL($A$2)+1)*($A$2:$C$5=$F$2));COL(B1)));"")}`